# Looking for a manual for GNOME3 Shell CSS Entries

Tags: css, gnome-shell

I am trying to customise and tune a downloaded GNOME Shell Theme. I managed to change colours of top and bottom panels and got rid of rounded corners. However, I was not successful to find CSS entries for other things. Is there any official manual which explains the CSS entries?

I provided a screenshot which shows that there is still a very thin horizontal line right under the panel. I'd like to change the colour to something darker.

Apart from that I would looking for to changes colours of buttons. When I mouse over Activities, Applications, Places (buttons) they become black. I'd like to change it to while. Also, when buttons are active their background-color-gradient changes to blue-grey. I'd like to have a solid medium dark grey colour.

Also, inside opened windows (when I click on Applications), I would also change a background colour of links to group of applications.

Thanks for any advises.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know the technical documentation for GNOME3 is sparse at best and has been forever as is the case with most open source projects. Volunteers want to work on fun design and features, not boring documentation. Your best bet is to look at source code and a bunch of other themes and try to learn from that.

Comment: I understand. I am trying to figure out how the theme file works but after making many changes without success I gave up. I was hoping someone could help here.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the manual you are looking for, but I can say that you can see the source code of that panel, for example here:

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/3.30.1/js/ui/panel.js

and search all lines with **style_class** text to discover CSS entries that you can configure in your **gnome-shell.css** of your theme.

There are more components that you can explore here:

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/tree/3.30.1/js/ui

and for example, here I found old documentation about **St** objects:

https://developer.gnome.org/st/stable/

like **St.Bin**, etc... but it is not updated.. but you can explore **St** source code here:

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/tree/3.30.1/src/st

I hope this have been helpful...